# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception

Tags: magento2, error, cli, file-permissions

**SOLVED** - see my answer below.

I changed my theme and all pages showed only html without any styling. Then I ran `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and after website doesnt work and every page shows *HTTP ERROR 500*.

Any idea what this error log below means?

nginx error log:

```
2017/01/25 16:10:44 [error] 1124#1124: *540 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/mg/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')
#1 /var/www/html/mg/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/m...')
#2 /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
#4 /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(155): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#5 /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Fr" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: edu.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "edu.dev"
```

Comment: After deploy, upgrade command, you should change permission for var, pub/static directory and it's 777.

Comment: 2017/01/25 16:10:44 [error] 1124#1124: *540 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/mg/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
 -> this means '/var/www/html/mg/var/page_cache' is not writable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to re-run permission commands on my magento 2 installation directory. Don't know why would I need to re-run them.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/mg`

Is this correct? Seems excessive permission to me. Maybe within a close test environment?

Comment: Isn't giving 777 permission to the whole mag dir is kinda risky ?

Comment: Perhaps, but when working locally @MohammedJoraid I don't see the huge security risks

Comment: @FooBar Absolutely. I wasn't aware of the assumption that it's a local environment.

Comment: Right - but just for `/var/www/html/mg/var`

Answer (score 3):

As this is a permissions issue you should run all commands from the CLI as the web server user. Typically it is `www-data` user, so after you set all permissions ([as magento devdocs recommends](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)) **DO NOT** execute:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Because the magento will generate all files with the `root` user and it will be the owner of the files. In this case web-server user `www-data` cant write this files without `+w` permission set for the `other`s.

**Right way**:

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

In this case the `www-data` user will be set as file owner and all should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must config the security context of the files and force it to be in the Read and Write mode.

This is the command:

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t directory_or_filename`

Comment: Thanks! this is useful when SELinux is in use

Answer (score 0):

As Siarhey Uchukhlebau mentions, you should **not** run the command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy using sudo. Instead you should create a new user that will own the magento filesystem, add that user to the web server group (if using apache2 this will be www-data), and then chown recursively all files on your magento installation. And use that same user to run any magento commands. So:

1. Create the user that will own the magento file system :

   ```
   sudo adduser magento
   ```

The name after adduser command is the name of your new user. In this case we will use magento as the user name for simplicity. Give it a password when prompted.

2. Add the new user to the web server group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG www-data magento
   ```
3. Assign the new user as the new owner of the magento file system:

   ```
   sudo chown -R magento:www-data ./
   ```

**Please not that you should only use ./ if you are inside your magento root directory. Replace this by your root installation path**

4. Log in as the new user:

   ```
    su - magento
   ```

Use this new user to run any magento commands, without using sudo

Answer (score 0):

give permission to var folder 777 and as well it's all subfolers 777 it worked for me