# I am getting error of page_cache is not writable in magento 2.2.5 in linux os

Tags: magento2, cache, permissions, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to add a grid in admin side. I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/var/page_cache" is not writable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/opt...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(157): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mage in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

[image]

I have tried

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/var/page_cache
```

Comment: check the link may help you [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156421/php-fatal-error-uncaught-zend-cache-exception)

Comment: Hi, I have already referred it. @CharulTyagi

Comment: Go to your var/ directory and set permission specially for page_cache directory to 777.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/var/page_cache i did this @CharulTyagi

Comment: Have you checked permission for root,var.page_cache directory that it is successfully set or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced same type of error few days ago.

You can fix it by following ways..

```
chmod 777 -R var/ generated/(root access if don't have root access try with sudo)
```

NP: *****you need to give permission every time when you use below cmd.*****

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

*So, you need to give proper permission of your application* .
you can follow below links.

[Check this link](https://www.letsknowit.com/magento2-files-and-folder-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

**You can fix it by following ways..**

```
 chown www-data -R /var/www/html/root
```